# golang 1.12 import relative directory module

Tags: go, module

go 1.12 how to import a relative path module.
e.g

```
demo_project
   - main.go
   -- demo
      - demo.go


demo.go:
pakcage demo
...
```

I have try to import "./demo" in main.go,but it's report a error message:
cannot find module for path _/home/xxx/mywork/go_project/grpc_demo/demo
how to import demo in main.go

Comment: What the content of `go.mod` file?

Comment: Always use the full import path, relative paths are not supported.

Comment: I have solved this problem. In go 1.12, import a package of relative path should import "demo_project/demo", but before 1.12, import "./demo"

Answer (score -3):

- **GO** wants to import the package from $GOPATH env at first. If **go** can't find the package, an error is raised.
- Add our project directory into **$GOPATH** env.

---

```
debug@ulab:/tmp/test$ go run main.go
main.go:3:8: cannot find package "mylib" in any of:
    /home/debug/.golang/go/src/mylib (from $GOROOT)
    /home/debug/.golang/gopath/src/mylib (from $GOPATH)
```

---

```
$ tree
.
├── main.go
├── src
│   └── hello
│       └── hello.go
└── start.sh

2 directories, 3 files
```

---

```
$ cat start.sh
#!/bin/sh

GOPATH="$(pwd):$(go env GOPATH)"

go run main.go
```

---

```
$ ./start.sh
Welcome to golang
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your answer? How does it solve the question?

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH,To learn more about the GOPATH environment variable, see 'go help gopath' in your console.

Comment: Please add all explanation to your answer, not to the comment section. And please don't use links only - keep in mind that others should be able to learn from your answer

Comment: Please see the error demo, and everything is clear.

Comment: @debug: the question is asking about modules, which doesn't use GOPATH